# InetAddress.getAllByName() does not work as advertised?

Tags: java

The following snippet returns only a single InetAddress with my hostname and the loopback address 127.0.1.1:

```
InetAddress[] allAddresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);
assert allAddresses.length == 1;
assert allAddresses[0].isLoopbackAddress();
```

However, I can find my non-loopback IP like so:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = networkInterfaces; e.hasMoreElements();) {
  NetworkInterface networkInterface = e.nextElement();
  Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
  for (Enumeration<InetAddress> eAddresses = inetAddresses; eAddresses.hasMoreElements();) {
    InetAddress address = eAddresses.nextElement();
    if (!address.isLoopbackAddress()) {
      return address;
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, I'm able to resolve my host name to the non-loopback IP using nslookup.

InetAddress.getAllByName() claims "given the name of a host, returns an array of its IP addresses, based on the configured name service on the system." Am I missing a configuration step?

Comment: **assert allAddresses.length == 1;** Why are you doing this?

Comment: Simply to illustrate that getAllByName() is only returning an array of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

For this method, on Linux at least,OS will read values from /etc/hosts and if it finds anything it will return it.
And /etc/hosts probably only has

```
127.0.0.1 yourhostname
```

on  your system.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this behavior. If I add another IP address to /etc/hosts, it shows up. However, based on the javadoc it sounds like I should be able to get the same IP information as I can find with nslookup.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a documentation bug.

Comment: It probably asks operating system for it (`based on the configured name service on the system`). And OS returns what it thinks is right. But `configured name service on the system` is not necessarily nslookup. It does not make sense for OS to do ns lookup if it already has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to get the desired behavior in this instance is to use something like dnsjava: http://www.dnsjava.org/dnsjava-current/examples.html

The following solves the problem.

```
InetAddress[] allAddresses = org.xbill.DNS.Address.getAllByName(host);
```